# Browse nodes in differents levels with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm on a problem that is starting to get very boring. Indeed, here is the case on which I block:
Here is my example of my XML:

```
<Classification>
    <data>
        <value>String1</value>
        <value>String2</value>
        <value>content1</value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <value></value>
        <value></value>
        <value>
            <part>content3</part>
            <part>content2</part>
            <part>content1</part>
        </value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <value></value>
        <value></value>
        <value>content1</value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <value></value>
        <value></value>
        <value>
            <part>content2</part>
            <part>content4</part>
        </value>
    </data>
</Classification>
```

And here is the result I would like to have:

```
<Classification>
    <data>
        <value>content1</value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <value>content2</value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <value>content3</value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <value>content4</value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <value>String1</value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <value>String2</value>
    </data>
</Classification>
```

I want to explode my xml to have only unique values output. However, I can not solve the problem of value [3] which can be different.

I already use the previous-sibling and recursion. Here is my xsl I use:

```
<xsl:template name="clearClassificationWithPart">
    <xsl:param name="recursion"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$recursion > 0">
            <xsl:for-each select="data[
                not(./value[$recursion] = preceding-sibling::data/value[$recursion])
                and not(./value[$recursion]/part = preceding-sibling::data/value[$recursion])
                and not(./value[$recursion] = preceding-sibling::data/value[$recursion]/part)
                and not(./value[$recursion]/part = preceding-sibling::data/value[$recursion]/part)]">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="./value[$recursion]/part">
                        <xsl:for-each select="./value[$recursion]/part">
                            <data>
                                <value><xsl:value-of select="." /></value>
                            </data>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <data>
                            <value><xsl:value-of select="./value[$recursion]" /></value>
                        </data>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>      
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:call-template name="clearClassificationWithPart">
                <xsl:with-param name="recursion" select="$recursion - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I use XSLT 1.0.

Someone have an idea?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using?

Comment: For PHP I use libxslt and for Java I use Xalan.

Comment: Both support the EXSLT `set:distinct()` extension function - why don't you use it?

Comment: Thank you for this remark! I'm begginner and my xsl files are very basic so I don't need to use external library. I tried to use it but does'nt work :/. This function it's like preceding-sibling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a processor that supports the EXSLT `set:distinct()` extension function you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
extension-element-prefixes="set">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Classification">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(data/value/text() | data/value/part/text())">
           <data>
                <value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </value>
            </data>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Classification>
  <data>
    <value>String1</value>
  </data>
  <data>
    <value>String2</value>
  </data>
  <data>
    <value>content1</value>
  </data>
  <data>
    <value>content3</value>
  </data>
  <data>
    <value>content2</value>
  </data>
  <data>
    <value>content4</value>
  </data>
</Classification>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It's work! When I tried it, I used "or" and not "|".You saved me!